# Imported variable in nodejs showing undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

I'm new to nodejs. trying out a simple export(using module.export) and import using require() but when i try to print out the imported constants i get "undefined". Please help. Code provided below. Also i realise there is the export/import ES6 way but i'd like to fix this particular error by still using module.export and require(). Same error on intelliJ IDEA and VScode.

constants.js

```
const fname = 'Abdulraqib';
const lname = 'Olayanju';

module.export = {
    fname : fname
};
```

index.js

```
const name = require('./constant');

console.log(name.fname);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fe-workshop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"

}
```

Comment: It has to be `module.exports` in your contants.js file.

Comment: check the name of the file too. It should be `./constants` where you import I believe. Also check the path of your files.

Comment: Yeah... It's a typo the file name is constant.js... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `module.exports` not `module.export`

```
const fname = 'Abdulraqib';
const lname = 'Olayanju';

module.exports = {
    fname : fname
};
```